# Are worker threads in ForkJoinPool are Daemon threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, forkjoinpool

I am reading about Fork/Join Framework from book [Java - The Complete Reference](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/java-the-complete/9781260440249/ch28.xhtml). It says that `ForkJoinPool` uses daemon threads :

> ForkJoinPool uses daemon threads. A daemon thread is automatically
> terminated when all user threads have terminated. Thus, there is no
> need to explicitly shut down a ForkJoinPool. However, with the
> exception of the common pool, it is possible to do so by calling
> shutdown( ). The shutdown( ) method has no effect on the common pool.

1. Does this means all `ForkJoinWorkerThread` are daemon threads?
2. Since daemon threads are [low priority threads](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/daemon-thread-java/), then we shouldn't use `ForkJoinPool` for important tasks?
3. If worker threads are not daemon threads, then does `shutdown()` waits for worker threads to finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.**

```
jshell> ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() ->  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getClass() + " isDaemon?  " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()))
class java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread isDaemon?  true

jshell>
```

**A**: yes, they are daemon threads.

**2.**

```
jshell> new Thread(() -> System.out.println("isDaemon? " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon() + " priority:" +  Thread.currentThread().getPriority())).start()
isDaemon? false priority:5

jshell> ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> System.out.println("isDaemon? " + Thread.currentThread().isDaemon() + " priority:" +  Thread.currentThread().getPriority()))
isDaemon? true priority:5
```

**A**: ForkJoinPool by default creates threads with the same priority as any other thread.

**3.**

from javadoc of ForkJoinPool#commonPool

> Returns the common pool instance. This pool is statically constructed; its run state is unaffected by attempts to shutdown() or shutdownNow(). However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program System.exit(int). Any program that relies on asynchronous task processing to complete before program termination should invoke commonPool().awaitQuiescence, before exit.

**A**: ForkJoinPool ignores shutdown, but application can call **awaitQuiescence​** to ensure that all task are complete.

Answer (score 2):

1. yes
2. no, the priority of daemon thread is the same as that of ordinary threads.
   Moreover, you can set their priority to the desired level.
   The referenced article just proposes to use daemon threads for less important tasks, as they are not guaranteed to finish their work when JVM exits.
3. yes